# django allauth facebook social login callback failure

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth

I configured my facebook app for social login Client OAuth Settings as
and I saved. My app is currently live but I did not submit "Submit Items for Approval" though.

```
Valid OAuth redirect URIs = http://www.jeviz.com/
```

1-User clicks following URL for sign up

```
http://www.jeviz.com/accounts/facebook/login/?process=login
```

2-User go to facebook click OK

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jeviz.com%2Faccounts%2Ffacebook%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2F&state=SXmYnAEwS21Z&scope=email&client_id=688227877985116&response_type=code
```

3-Then redirect URL leads to:

```
http://www.jeviz.com/accounts/facebook/login/callback/?code=AQCUL6tqM7f0jDHp_5fKgVRTtiAzYV_2MAU53VRNN8PGvtRetCbCIqXG3JXrf_tr4xYtqlDVlYFgz8aZSzYmNDdd50ZxqkWEj2m78mpmlJe-7ix47oxH8m3DW0ZUC0EAbqIt_Nz3fzHDbs0o_3NcilGZYRy5-I90W3m7UUnR68_dRpfr829snFbYELV6ifjSAOOKWj4mYIiEwXsnrdVUTdebiqBMLBssf3UUuBh1ta-gNzZyTKuFjfvwr_TVL4ykd8OCJ5lBUCUV8QrCZoptex9OJDHWL7RAKCANj976Ua3tsL3KN89hhK1S0EWV9qrvkB5qCeqinAJYParSq1ilB6Pq&state=SXmYnAEwS21Z#_=_
```

and gave me

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

as you see redirect url is not www.jeviz.com as suggested in the official document[django-allauth providers](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#facebook)
At the end a user is created but not logged in. But If you user try to login manually by clicking social Facebook button she could login. As I stated above first signup redirect callback was wrong and user was not logged in for the first time.
What am I doing wrong?

My configuration

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('amazon_advertising:home')
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('account_login')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('account_logout')

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 7
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "optional"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it. When I first add facebook as Social applications in django allauth my facebook redirect URL was `/accounts/facebook/login/?process=login` . I have changed it to www.jeviz.com later. I deleted facebook social app and re-created it now it works when signup! It redirect to my homepage.